# ASP.Net Core launch website via Visual Studio vs. Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Environment:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.3.9
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.3.9+29509.3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752
```

I created an EMPTY ASP.NET Core 3.0 web project (just learning .Net Core - so trying to keep things simple).

When I build the project (Configuration = Debug) and then launch the website, the Visual Studio output window shows the following:

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44308/" for site "website0" application "/"
Registration completed for site "website0"
IIS Express is running.
```

The output shows the website is running on port: 44308,  If I understand correctly, the port number comes from the launchSettings.json file which VS uses when the website is launched:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64501",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
```

However, I typically use COMMAND LINE tools to build, deploy and run (much easier to document text commands rather than take screen snapshots of GUI tools that change every year).

When I build and publish the website to a test directory, and then launch the website using the dotnet command:

```
> dotnet website0.dll
```

The console output shows the following:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

My questions:

1. I cannot find the port numbers in any configuration file (.json or web.config) within the published directory - so where are these port numbers coming from?
2. How can I configure / control which ports are used when the website is published to either a test or production environment (using command line tools)? - is this done via a .pubxml file?  If so, what node(s) must be included within the .pubxml file?  ... Or is this done via some other config file when the website is launched, i.e.: web.config?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May have found the answer to the 5000 and 5001 ports at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#endpoint-configuration

Comment: That same link also tells you how to control the ports, so you effectively answered your own questions. Either delete it, or post/accept your own answer below.

Comment: @Lex Li - yes, was just out of the office, have updated with answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have found the answer to the 5000 and 5001 ports at:

[Endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#endpoint-configuration)